# Homechart docker container not able to connect to postgres docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking

I have installed homechart docker container on my Synology using the following settings (using portainer).

```
version: "3"
services:
  homechart:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      HOMECHART_POSTGRESQL_HOSTNAME: postgres
      HOMECHART_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxx
      HOMECHART_POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: postgres
      
      HOMECHART_APP_ADMINEMAILADDRESSES: abc@gmail.com
      HOMECHART_APP_BASEURL: https://web.homechart.app
      HOMECHART_APP_DEBUG: true
      
      HOMECHART_SMTP_FROMADDRESS: abc@gmail.com
      HOMECHART_SMTP_HOSTNAME: xxx.synology.me
      HOMECHART_APP_NOEMAILDOMAINS:
      HOMECHART_SMTP_REPLYTO: noreply@xxx.synology.me
#      HOMECHART_SMTP_PORT:
#      HOMECHART_SMTP_PASSWORD:
#      HOMECHART_SMTP_USERNAME:
      
    image: candiddev/homechart:latest
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
    restart: always
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxx
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres: {}
```

They are both part of the same docker network but for some reason the homechart docker is not able to connect to postgres container. Following is the error i see in the homechart container.

```
2:5432: connect: connection timed out' requestID='b2179ea2971a6f5f4c1537ac0a8ea1cf'
[ERROR] function="models.Setup:885" error='Unable to connect to database' success=false status=false
[ERROR] function="tasks.CheckUpdate:178" error='Unable to perform action' success=false status=false debug='Get "https://web.homechart.app/api?p=server": dial tcp: lookup web.homechart.app on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:42087->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout'
```

How do I fix this issue?

Please let me know what other information i can put here (and how to get it) to help resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with homechart, but one possibility is that homechart is attempting to connect to postgres before postgres is ready to handle connections. What happens if you first bring up the postgres container (`docker-compose up -d postgres`), wait for it to be ready, and then bring up homechart?

Comment: I have tried this (waiting for postgres to start before starting homechart) but i get the same error.